# Android Studio - How to get user details from mobile number?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing and app which is nearly similar to OLA/Uber for my project. I noticed that after successful mobile authentication, OLA/Uber app automatically gets the persons details from mobile number like the persons name, registered Email with the mobile number.

So my question is, is there any method so that I can implement in my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get user details from mobile number. You can, however, get user details from `AccountManager`. Use below code

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

For more information google how to get google account information in android

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't get name and address from mobile number without government permission....

but you can get these details from google signin api

Comment: yup the government wont give that permission.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little more complicated - OLA/Uber/Viber etc... - these apps don't really have a world-wide database of names/number that that can query get people's details by phone.

Instead, because of their large user-base and the fact that they have access to people's contacts on the devices where their apps are installed, plus they usually have a registration process which associates number to person name / payment details, they are able to "compose" such database that is actually much more up-to-date than any offline phonebook. But of course - they keep their data to them.